# Can I uninstall EasyBCD after I have removed the ubuntu entry?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-10, easybcd

I was facing many problems while using Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10 so I removed Ubuntu by deleting its partition and followed some steps I found in a video to remove GRUB:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Then I also removed the Ubuntu entry from EasyBCD

[image: screenshot of it]

Now I just want to uninstall EasyBCD. Is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the EasyBCD Windows bootloader editor program anymore, so you can uninstall it from Windows 10 and Windows will still be able to boot.